# Reciving data from python server to a client in android studio- Java

Tags: java, android, python

I'm using websockets in order to deliver strings from python server to android studio java client. I checked the string that are send by the server (by printing it in python) and that works, so I guess the problem is how I get the data in java.

I need to send things like this:
I have a list in python that saves data. I don't Know her length, so I uses `len(my_list)` to send. For sure, I have even cells in the list, I need to send double cells each time. That is my code in Java:

The Server Handler:

```
package cyber_pro4.com;


import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;

public class ServerHandler
{

    private OkHttpClient client;
    private WebSocket ws;
    private WebSocketListener listener;

    private Context context;

    private String message = "";

    public ServerHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        listener = new SocketListener();
    }

    public void start() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://10.0.0.22:8080").build();
        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        Toast.makeText(context, "connected to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        ws.send(message);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        System.out.println("BATMAN GET " + message);
        String msg = message;
        message = "";
        return msg;
    }

    public void resetMessage() { message = ""; }

    public void closeConnection() {
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }

    private final class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            message = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            webSocket.close(1000, null);
        }
    }

}
```

The way I get the data:

```
       ServerHandler serverHandler2;
       serverHandler2 = new ServerHandler(Fish_info.this);
       serverHandler2.start();
       serverHandler2.sendMessage("send pic of fish"); 

       String message,message2;

       int i = 1;

       while (i > 0)
       {

           message = "";
           while ((message = serverHandler2.getMessage()).equals("")) {
           } //this string 

           if (!(message.equals("false"))) // if the server return false- that mean this is the end of my list
           {
               message2 = "";
               while ((message2 = serverHandler2.getMessage()).equals("")) {
               } //this string is a info

              Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Toast.makeText(this, message2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(this, "There you go- the end of the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               i = -5;
           }

       }
```

I only toasts the first two cells of the list, even if the list have 4 cells.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, for those who will need it in the future- I just did a `serverHandler2.sendMessage("send pic of fish");` before I recive every data from the server. (recive by the code of `message = "";
           while ((message = serverHandler2.getMessage()).equals("")) {
           } //this string`)